# Javascript Regular expression (?i)^inf

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know what this regular expression refers.

`(?i)^inf`

With examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not Valid in JavaScript

JavaScript doesn't support inline modifiers such as `(?i)` (see below). This regex is not proper JavaScript syntax.

---

### In many other flavors... Any string that starts with `inf`, case-insensitive.

In .NET, Java, PCRE, Perl, Python, Ruby and a number of other engines, `(?i)` turns on case-insensitivity.

**Sample matches**

```
infact
inFahrenheit
INF
INFO
INfine
```

**How it Works**

- `(?i)` turns on case-insensitivity mode
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `inf` matches literal characters

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to figure : type `/(?i)^inf/` in the console.

Conclusion : it's an invalid regular expression in JavaScript.

But I guess you saw this regex in another language. If you want to [use flags in JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags), the syntax is different :

```
/^inf/i
```

What it means is : a string starting with `"inf"`, with case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it supports in Java-script or not.

But i got to know `(?i)` means case-insensitive

Example:-

`(?i)integer  matches Integer, inTeger, etc,.`